# 2nd Wifi connected PC loses connectivity seemingly when other PC falls asleep?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, connection, modem, desktop-computer

I have a PC connected via ethernet to an ubee modem/router for internet access. A 2nd PC in another room is connected via a usb wifi connector.  Often I am told the other PC loses connectivity and if I wake the ethernet connected PC from sleep mode or turn it back on, then the wifi PC regains connectivity.  I do not want to leave the main PC on all the time, is there a way to keep the wifi PC connected constantly without having to leave the main PC running?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you want to get a router with WiFi and Ethernet. Connect your modem to that and then connect your PCs to it. Then it will be fine as long as that is on.

Comment: Thank you.  This is supposed to be a modem/router all in one deal.  Would that make a difference?

Comment: Well, it would except that the other PC is using Wifi. If both PCs were wired you'd be able to just get by with a switch. You could use a switch and a Wifi hotspot. Judging by the fact that it looks like you have it setup so that the Wifi only PC is connecting through the other PC I'm guessing that you are using that main PC as a hotspot. For price and convenience it is probably going to be best to just get a router with built-in wifi. If the modem also has a switch then you can possibly save money by getting a hotspot only. Last time I priced them it was only a $10 savings (cheap) though.